# streaking image with opencv

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv, memory-leaks

So I've been working on some code for a couple weeks and it is far from complete, However the one thing keeping me from moving forward is a strange problem which I cannot figure out. I've been stuck for a few days now

The code below is for a program which accepts to command line arguments, an infile and an outfile. The infile will be a small square binary tif image, somewhere between 200x200 and 400x400. At this point the program should tile the image, stretching each part to various lengths. The outfile should have a height of 768 pixels and a width in the ballpark of 50k to 60k pixels. I apologize, but I can't supply them for example, they are confidential.
While it does work, sort of, it only replicates images to around 34k pixels and stops. The last row continues to display a black streak to the end.
I think the problem is coming from my create1track() function. I have tried optimizing it with very few changes. If I use a while loop as opposed to a for loop I get three black streaks as opposed to one. Does anyone have any suggestions on why it might do this?
It's a pretty simple function. I don't see why it shouldn't work

I'm posting my entire code, hoping for some advice. A copy is stored is stored here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sp153rz252uikue/main_backup.cpp

I'd accept any other criticism/input, just be nice, I just started teaching myself c++ about 2 months ago and since I'm pretty new to programming in general, I'm sure there is plenty of things I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just some advice. Since your using C++, it would be *much* easier to work with the C++ wrappers. Not only is it more efficient but it also provides a number of additional festures. And considering you still have little code, the transition wouldn't be too hard. Check it out: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html

Comment: You are probably facing [this issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1337). (`warpAffine` internally uses `remap`)

Comment: yep, thats gotta be it. That is going to be a pain to fix. Oh well, at least I understand the problem. As for the wrappers, Riddler. Could you please elaborate. I apologize but I'm still pretty new. I looked up some info on wrappers and don't entirely understand why they would make code I already have written easier.